# Do I need to train my neural network everytime I run it?

Tags: python, neural-network, training-data

I am trying machine learning for the first time, and am playing around with a handwriting recognition NN (in Python). I just wanted to know whether or not I need to train the model every time I run it, or if it 'saves' the training. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you wrote the net and whether or not you ever save it to disk. If the net is destroyed when you close the program, obviously you'll have to rebuild it every time. I don't think you've given near enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Remember that a computer program does exactly what it is told. If you are using a library of some sort, then you can see if the library saves the NN state after training. If this is not done automatically by the library, then yes, you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: i am not sure what other information to include, would you like to see the code?

Comment: @TarunPrakash Show the relevent code. And include information about if you ever serialize it. And if you are saving the net perfectly, why would it lose information? There must be some information you're neclecting.

Comment: At the very least, what library are using? Tensorflow, PyTorch, etc? Try [reading the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).

Comment: I am using TensorFlow, I will look at their docs to see if there is anything there

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't actually start the training yet, I just wanted to know before I started, if I had to train it everytime. Thank you for the information, however, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using an already ready library it 'saves' the training only if you write a part of code to save it. The simplest way is to generate a TXT with a list of all the weights after the training and load it with a specific function.